# Normalize data in stack bar using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Is there any way to normalize each group and plot as stacked bar using matplotlib?

```
# create stacked bar chart
ax = df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
 
# labels for x & y axis
plt.xlabel('Categories')
plt.ylabel('Number of tweets')
plt.legend(loc="best", ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5, 1, 0.5))

# title of plot
plt.title('Health-related category tweet')
```

[image]

Comment: it might be easier to create extra columns in your data frame for the normalised data, and then plot those?

Comment: @tmdavison thanks for the comment. yes, I manipulated the dataframe before ploting the graph but also wonder whether matplolib might have the option for nomalization.